# Add class, closest div

Tags: jquery, html, css

Almost have 3 hours spend on this. Nothing found.

Here is my code.. 3 separate URL on file. (Updated)

```
<div id="menu">
<a href="blue.php">
<div class="list">
Content_here
</div>
</a>

<a href="yallow.php">
<div class="list">
Content_here
</div>
</a>

<a href="black.php">
<div class="list">
Content_here
</div>
</a>
</div>
```

Add class on current URL

```
<div id="menu">
<a href="#">
<div class="list active">
content_here
</div>
</a>
</div>
```

Here is:

```
$("#menu a").each(function(index) {
    if($.trim(this.href) == window.location) {
        $(this).closest('div').addClass("active");
    }
});
```

No `active` `class` on current `URL`. ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **[`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)** method is using for getting the ancestor element.Since the div is inside the `a` use **[`children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/)** or **[`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)** method.

```
$(this).find('div').addClass("active");
```

---

Or [select it based on the `this` context](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-selector-context).

```
$('div', this).addClass("active");
```

---

Although for getting the current page url use [`window.location.href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/href).

```
$("#menu a").each(function(index) {
    if($.trim(this.href) == window.location.href) {
        $('div', this).addClass("active");
    }
});
```

or use condition as `window.location.pathname == $(this).attr('href')`

Comment: I updated my question, there is more than one URL on file.

Comment: @lovepeople You want to update every url .... also change your condition to `$.trim(this.href) == '#'`

Comment: @lovepeople : also change your condition to `$(this).attr('href') == '#'`

Comment: @lovepeople : make more clear about ... ___`current url`___

Comment: @lovepeople use `window.location.href `

Comment: @lovepeople : glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("[url="+window.location.origin+"]").addClass("active")
```

Please note that `window.location` is an object and not a string